# What exactly are the tradeoffs between terminating a transmission line carrying a digital signal in 50 ohms versus high impedance?

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I have a black box that outputs a 1.28 MHz clock signal that I need to buffer and distribute. If that signal is terminated into 50 ohms the voltage is so slow <1.5V it won't register as high for the logic family and voltages I want to use. Into High-Z it swings up to a full 3V which is well above the 2V threshold for TTL and CMOS.

What is the tradeoff from switching to 50 ohms to High-Z? Is it noise? Ringing?

Comment: Ringing, which occurs whenever there is a mismatch between the receiver and the transmission line.  There are lots of discussions here on this topic.  Try searching for "ringing", "transmission line", or "termination".

Comment: Source termination with a high-z end works only in a point to point link; otherwise for anything bussed you need matched termination at the ends, and line receivers capable of working with the actual line voltage, rather than the reflected doubling which would be corrupted by conflict between forward and reflected waves anywhere but the *actual* end.

Comment: the 1.28 MHz is irrelevant, the word 'clock' is important. It sounds like a square wave. What is the risetime? If it's a few nS, then you do need to worry about a few inches of line.

Comment: Would a simple BJT do the trick? 1.5 V should be more than enough it.

Comment: One way to handle this is to buffer the signal at the black box. You could use video buffers (which are designed to driver 75 Ohm loads). Some video buffers can drive multiple 75 Ohm loads. You could also distribute the clock using LVDS buffers, and then you could use twisted pair for distribution.

Answer (score 4):

On many electronic designs transmission line effects do not need to be considered until about 40MHz or 50MHz.

For a 1.28MHz signal, a transmission line is most likely not needed. The wavelength is over 200m so unless the cabling system is on that scale, reflections and ringing are not likely to be noticeable. This means if you use high impedance as a clock load it will be fine.

However, if you are running the clock to multiple sources fanout will need to be considered, as if the total impedance (resistive load and capacitive load) is too low the clock driver will not be able to provide sufficient current to raise the voltage to the high level. So check the fanout and use a sufficient driver for the load.

If transmission line effects are not negligible, then a wave on a high impedance load could reflect back to the source. In this case the [reflection coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient) should be calculated and the load adjusted.

Comment: Thank you! Why didn't I think of that?! Can you elaborate on the tradeoffs when the transmission line model is needed? edit: except its a pulse train so the spectral content is not just at 1.28 MHz.....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you find the wavelength and then see if your design needs to use transmission lines.

Comment: Because its a pulse train its spectral content is not at a signal frequency, if you just look at the wavelength of a 1.28 MHz signal that doesn't tell you the full picture

Comment: single frequency**